# In what rule book is the awakened familiar background introduced?

Tags: dnd-5e, product-identification, background

I saw this as an option in a dnd beyond campaign that I'm apart of, in what book does it appear (and page if possible)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Awakened Familiar is not a player character background in any official Dungeons & Dragons 5th edition source book published by Wizards of the Coast.

If you see "Awakened Familiar" as a character background option in D&D Beyond, then the most likely explanation is that it's homebrew content added by the host. D&D Beyond allows a campaign host to [share homebrew content](https://dndbeyond.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/115010423427-Homebrew-Sharing) with other users in their campaign. This character background could be something that they created or found elsewhere.

In D&D Beyond, the only match I could find for "Awakened Familiar" is in homebrew creations. You can locate the list of user-submitted Homebrew Backgrounds by selecting the "Collections" menu (in the upper navigation bar), then under "Homebrew" (on the right side) select "Browse Backgrounds".

Searching online suggests a 5e-compatible source book "[Remarkable Lineages: Awakened Familiar](https://www.drivethrurpg.com/product/306187/Remarkable-Lineages-Awakened-Familiar)" on DriveThruRPG. This is published by a 3rd party, and is not official material for D&D 5e. You could ask the campaign host if they're using this source.

Comment: This is also a [kickstarter](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/calltoadventure/unfamiliar-1) that deals with familiars that gain classes and levels